# How to use --file=script-file option to input a file to search and replace in sed command

Tags: linux

I am doing a jenkins migration using jenkins-cli where in one step I am using sed command to replacing values manually as like below :

```
sed 's/mukesh/architect/g' target_file
```

But I would like to enter all the possible values in Input file with two column with delimeter as `=` and supply to target file

Input file looks like
ex:

> mukesh=architect
>   abdul=manager

Now I want to use this file as input in sed command for search and replace in my target file. Instead of using `s///g` manually, I want to use the below option that I found in man page

```
-f script-file, --file=script-file
```

But not sure how to use this input file to auto search and replace the pattern in to the target file. It would be grateful if I get any samples, examples.

Comment: Transform the "input file" from the format `a=b c=d ...` into format `s/a/b/g; s/c/d/g; ...` and pass that as first argument of `sed` command line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to read input file, parse it and update outfile.
Here I am reading input file, separating values based on delimeter "=" and then updating outfile/target file.

```
while read name
do 
x=`echo $name|cut -d"=" -f1`
y=`echo $name|cut -d"=" -f2`
sed -i "s/$x/$y/g" outfile
done < inputfile
```

This should solve your problem. Let me know if you are looking for something else or extra.cheers :)

Comment: Yes this is also an other option which works for me. Thanks a lot